# Script to parse a proto file and generate Plain C Structures

Tags: python, c, protocol-buffers, proto

I am trying to parse available proto files in a directory and create corresponding plain old C structures. All the current libraries are creating C++ classes, which is not supported in my repo (Very outdated repo :) )Is there any library which can used for this purpose.

For eg. 
[address.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/examples/addressbook.proto)

This proto file should be parsed and should be able to create a structure like the following. A sample extract.

```
struct PhoneNumber_s {
    char number[15]
    PhoneType type;
} PhoneNumber_t;

enum PhoneType {
   MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
}
```

Generating the code might be straight forward based on type. But parser (python or any other lang) is the essential piece of information that is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into the various protobuf libraries for C?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't do it in a way that makes sense. Your best bet, other than manually creating the corresponding C structs, is to write a short program that takes the outputs of the protobuf compiler and uses reflection to derive the field names and types, and then generates C source from them. Then, of course, you'll have to figure out how to do serialization/deserialization from C, but that's another show.